# How to send HTTP GET request to REST API via cURL using PHP and call method from REST API with cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm using `PHP` and `cURL`.
I want to send HTTP `GET` request to `REST` `API` and I want to call method from `REST API`.
 How can i make via `cURL` using `PHP`? I have `API` `URL` and Key.
 I must send my key with URL and I need method inside `REST API`.
 What I need to do?
 At the same time, i have to send basic authentication on all requests and I'll get `JSON` data.
How can i do?

Thanks.
Regards

this is my code

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(   
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                           
);             
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: $headers = ['Content-Type: application/json'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

Comment: Dilek hanım çok teşekkürler denedim fakat yine bir sonuç alamadım. Boş ekran dönüyor.. Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded hatası.

Comment: url ile giriş yapmak mı istiyorsun ? login with url ?

Comment: Linke her istek attığımda basic authentication ile username ve password göndermem gerekiyor. Aynı zamanda URL'deki methodu çağırmam gerekiyor SOAP gibi. When i send request to URL, i must login basic authentication and i must call method on URL like SOAP

Comment: let me try your code

Comment: thanks. I'm waiting your feedbacks

Comment: Add user credentials in url link EDIT nvm I edited.

Comment: Actualy you dont need 
 `CURLOPT_USERNAME, $username,
 CURLOPT_USERPWD, $password,` credentials in answer, I just let them stay because they were in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. Login is successful and access provided. Also i need call method on URL. Example: getProducts() like. This method on URL and i should send parameters with method. Thanks again. I'm very happy for your help.

Comment: Glad you made it work, accept answer,  if it helped, and ask another question for listing products.

Comment: Hi, i took HTTP STATUS 401 ERROR, This request requires HTTP authentication (). Why? my information is true. Can u help me?

Comment: Change : CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER   => array(
                                "Accept: application/json"
                                ),

Comment: Hi again, this code is runing. I have to call method inside WSDL with cURL. How can i do? So like this => i sended to request. And must come response me from service. like getCities(@param). Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and changed variables into array.
Added httpheaders, useragents.
And save to cookies and cookie location.
 And tested:

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$url = "http://localhost/html/login";
$send = "?username=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME, $username,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD, $password,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $send,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER   => array(
                                "Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4", 
                                "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
                                "Connection: keep-alive"
                                ),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookies.txt", 
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookies.txt",
    CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://localhost/html/login",
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate'
)); //gzip, if modul on
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```