# cUrl working fine on localhost but it's not working on server and only shows blank page

Tags: php, remote-access, php-curl

When I run the below code on server it only shows the blank page and suddenly stop further execution, I also checked the cUrl on server which is installed.

Here is my code.

```
$ftp_server = 'ftps://'.'server/Voorraadtonen link.csv'; 
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$ftp_server));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'username'.':'.'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 990);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
echo $output; exit;
```

Comment: read your error_log file and enable error reporting on curl or php error 
 reporting `if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}`

Comment: already enabled error reporting error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: You should have error then, use my code given in comment and **read your error_log file**

Comment: I used it but nothing is showing

Comment: Try this in your url `curl -u user:password 'ftps://mysite/%2fusers/myfolder/myfile/csv' -o ~/folder/link.csv`

Comment: I dont think you can get anything from this url ftps://'.'server/Voorraadtonen link.csv

Comment: Do you get anything in `$error_no`?

Comment: No, I don't get anything in $error_no

Answer (score 1):

**Latest update!**

You have more than 1 errors in your codes,

> you are using FTPS in url which requires SSL verification, and its false in
>   your codes.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
//Dont use try! you shouldnt use
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
```

They should be true : `SSL` doesnt support true so they should be like following on @dharman warn in another answer.

> But turning ssl true will require another setup like `cacert` file
>   etc. lik so

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//and include cacert.pem
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
```

Download cacert file here : https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

2.Your url is not a true url `$ftp_server = 'ftps://'.'server/Voorraadtonen link.csv';`, this url will get nothing, but it should return an error atleast in `error_log` file, as you said all errors reporting are enabled

3.Your code should look like this

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("link.csv", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.site.com/link.csv"); 
//Make sure for correct url
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
//Make sure for correct url
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
//Make sure for your ftp credentials
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); //20 seconds will be enough
curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_errno($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

1 more thing left headers should not be required but in case its required.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); //Or
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Now it should work without any problem

**NOTE :** Example code is a working example you can edit it to your requirements

**UPDATE :** After modification you said you did in your codes (*Still not showing us*), finaly we get an error. once again I am asking you to add modified code into your question.

> Error_no 28 cURL error 28: Connection timed out

the cURL 28 error occurs when the cURL request isn’t completed in a certain amount of time.

This happens when the cURL timeout value is set too low or when a firewall is blocking the cURL request.

Another possibility is a security module, for example the Apache mod_security module.

To fix the cURL error 28 you can contact your hosting provider.

So basicaly!

> Your server is blocking. your credentials not match to required
>   credentails. SSL is required by server, but you are not setting it up.
>   Your function runing max of your Server Memory Limits settings.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp.site.com/link.csv"); 
//make sure your path to file is correct
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
//make sure your login credentials correct
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
//Set timeout for connection
    curl_exec($curl);
    echo curl_errno($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
//Get errors
    curl_close($curl);
//Importand close curl connection.
```

Comment: @HaqNawaz update question and show what you did please

Comment: I am running the same code on localhost which is working and puling the data but on server it's not working even it's not showing any error, and I did enabled error reporting and increased execution time but nothing is showing.

Comment: Localhost and live servers are working different, 1 of them is `SSL` localhost doesnt require, but live servers does, `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` should be enabled on live but not required on local, http headers might be required on live server, there are tons of things I can tell, so you want to make it work ? edit your question and add latest code you tried. and **use the example in my question** its working fine I tested it peronaly. and add others step by step, so you can find what is wrong, we cant have a guess about your setup and your codes if you dont show us and not trying what we say.

Comment: See This is well another function by me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422673/12232340

Comment: I made changes on it and it's giving me 28 in error

Comment: @HaqNawaz Nice atleast showing us something. you should try my code, error means timeout connection, so, 1.paste this `curl_close($ch);` under `$curl error_no` and remove `exit;` in you code, can be your curl is working infinite. 2.Set time out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);`. 3. Some times headers causing that problem too, so, turn headers to false and see result if it causing a problem. I updated my answer, added timeout. and plase add latest code you tried and get error 28.

Comment: Thanks for answering I appreciate it. I also increased the timeout to 500 but then it's showing nothing curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);

Comment: @HaqNawaz try second code in answer as its dont change anything, just put path to your file and your login infos, and see if it works.